# Pop off valve on my water well

Tags: well-pump

My 75 psi pop off valve had blown out 3 x’s already and the pressure gauge is reading 80, I bought a 100 so I don’t have to keep changing it out is this ok? What could be causing this problem? It just started a couple years ago with 1 instance now it’s several!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a well system, overpressure is generally tied to an improperly set, or not correctly functioning pressure switch.

Hardly surprising for a 75PSI overpressure to pop off if you've set the pressure at 80. Presumably the 75 PSI was installed with the system set to operate at 20-40, 30-50, 40-60 or maybe 50-70, though 50-70 is unusually high for pump settings. 40-60 is typically the highest "normal" setting, but sometimes city folks move to the country and crank up the pressure without understanding the complete system effects (if you crank up the pressure, you really should add more pressure tank capacity as the tank drawdown is reduced with higher pressure settings, for one thing.)

If you haven't set the pressure at 80 and it's going to 80, something is not working right.

Comment: It’s a water well and it’s not set to 80 it’s the gauge that’s ready it also the system is set at 60 so it’s not coming into my house at 80! Thank you so much 